# with clause execution order

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a simplified scenario I have table **T** that looks somthing like:

```
Key  Value
1    NULL
1    NULL
1    NULL
2    NULL
2    NULL
3    NULL
3    NULL
```

I also have a very time-consuming function **Foo(Key)** which must be considered as a black box (I must use it, I can't change it).

I want to update table **T** but in a more efficient way than

```
UPDATE T SET Value = dbo.Foo(Key)
```

Basically I would execute **Foo** only one time for each **Key**.

I tried something like

```
WITH Tmp1 AS
(
   SELECT DISTINCT Key FROM T
)
, Tmp2 AS
(
   SELECT Key, Foo(Key) Value FROM Tmp1
)
UPDATE T
SET T.Value = Tmp2.Value
FROM T JOIN Tmp2 ON T.Key = Tmp2.Key
```

but unexpectedly computing time doesn't change at all, because Sql Server seems to run **Foo** again on every row.

Any idea to solve this without other temporary tables?

Comment: Is there another column that can be used to distinguish between the `1 NULL` rows (etc) ? Is `Value` always `NULL` to start with?

Comment: @AakashM well, I can start with Null for each row and I know Foo(Key) is always different from Null, if I get what you mean

Comment: Why do you want to avoid temporary tables?

Comment: @NenadZivkovic Exactly the same question I wanted to ask this moment :-)

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use a temporary table.  You don't have much control over how SQL Server decides to optimize its queries.

If you don't want a temporary table, you could do two updates:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set value = db.foo(key)
    where seqnum = 1;
```

Then you can run a similar update again:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, max(value) over (partition by id) as as keyvalue
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set value = keyvalue
    where value is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try it like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Foo(@TheKey INT) 
RETURNS INT 
AS 
BEGIN 
    RETURN (SELECT @TheKey*2); 
END
GO

CREATE TABLE #tbl(MyKey INT,MyValue INT);
INSERT INTO #tbl(MyKey) VALUES(1),(1),(1),(2),(2),(3),(3),(3); 

SELECT * FROM #tbl;

DECLARE @tbl2 TABLE(MyKey INT,TheFooValue INT);
WITH DistinctKeys AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT MyKey FROM #tbl
)
INSERT INTO @tbl2
SELECT MyKey,dbo.Foo(MyKey) TheFooValue
FROM DistinctKeys;

UPDATE #tbl SET MyValue=TheFooValue
FROM #tbl
INNER JOIN @tbl2 AS tbl2 ON #tbl.MyKey=tbl2.MyKey;

SELECT * FROM @tbl2;
SELECT * FROM #tbl;
GO

DROP TABLE #tbl;
DROP FUNCTION dbo.Foo;
```

Comment: I have considered this option, but I prefer avoid temporary tables (as I stated in my question)

Comment: @willy OK, what against a declared table variable? I edited my answer to reflect this approach. The only temp table now is the one I define to create a test sceanrio.